# What's wrong with Google+ notifications?

Tags: notifications, google-plus

The new black Google toolbar at the top of Google+ (and other Google products.) has many enhancements. And one of them is notifications. It's near the top right.

However even though there is nothing new to notify. It turns red and says "1". Even if I click and view the notifications it returns to zero but a minute later it says "1" again.

Does anyone know why?

I'm using Firefox. 5.0

Comment: I have seen this same behavior and used the "Send Feedback" tool to report it. It's likely a caching issue, as I've also seen the notifier stay at zero long after I've received an e-mail alert to an update.

Comment: Same here, even the Surplus extension notify me before the original notifications system.

Comment: Voting to close as the "new black bar" was removed from all Google products quite some time ago. Due to this, the information in this question is no longer relevant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You don't want to forget the fact that Google+ is still in the testing Phase with limited number of people. It is like beta testing page. I'd suggest using a different browser to try, like Chrome for example.

Also I saw many people have added an extension to Google Chrome because maybe they are having the same issue.

Also being a Google+ user , you can send your feedback to Google and report this issue.

So my solution for such an issue is to test another browser , or using [Google Chrome Surplus extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/pfphgaimeghgekhncbkfblhdhfaiaipf).

Personally when I receive a notification about something , I receive immediately a message in my Gmail inbox, and this extension notify me before the original notifications system , it doesn't notify at all sometimes.

See also this [topic](http://www.techtipsgeek.com/how-to-get-g-notifications-outside-google-plus/14342/).